# Converting CSS and HTML hamburger menu into a react component

Tags: javascript, html, css, reactjs, hamburger-menu

I am following a tutorial that creates an animated navbar and hamburger manu using css, html and javascript, and I want to create the navbar as a react component for my project.

The code that I am trying to covert is the following, which is an app.js file which is embedded in the html with  tags:

```
const navSlide = () => {
    const burger = document.querySelector('.burger');
    const nav = document.querySelector('.nav-links');

    burger.addEventListener('click', () => {
        nav.classList.toggle('nav-active');
    })
}

navSlide();
```

I have tried to implement this code into my navbar react component as follows:

```
import React from "react";

const NavBar = () => {
const nav = document.querySelector(".nav-links");

  return (
    <div className="navbar">
        <nav>
            <ul className="nav-links">
                <li>
                    <a href="#">Menu Item</a>
                </li>
            </ul>
        <div
            className="burger"
            onClick={() => {
                nav.classList.toggle("nav-active");
            }}
        >
          <div className="line1" />
          <div className="line2" />
          <div className="line3" />
        </div>
       </nav>
    </div>
  );
};

export default NavBar;
```

However this returns the error of:
"TypeError: Cannot read property 'classList' of null"

The CSS of .nav-active is as follows:

```
.nav-active {
  transform: translateX(0%);
}
```

The result of this I am expecting is for the navbar to toggle open and closed when the burger symbol is clicked

Comment: I guess you need a state for your NavBar, and in the click handler, update it: setState({isActive:true})

Comment: Don't use _selectors_ if you need to point a dom element, use _refs_, instead. Notice that if you "think" react also refs usage will be very rare

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The best option is to go with state. This is should work, have not tested though. ReactJS 16.8 is required for useState hook to work.

```
import React, {useState} from "react";

const NavBar = () => {
  const [navOpened, setNavOpened] = useState(false);
  const navClassNames = navOpened ? 'nav-links nav-active' : 'nav-links';

  return (
    <div className="navbar">
        <nav>
            <ul className={navClassNames}>
                <li>
                    <a href="#">Menu Item</a>
                </li>
            </ul>
        <div
            className="burger"
            onClick={() => setNavOpened(!navOpened)}
        >
          <div className="line1" />
          <div className="line2" />
          <div className="line3" />
        </div>
       </nav>
    </div>
  );
};
```

Answer (score 0):

To refer to DOM elements you should be using ref, you can use a `useRef` hook [docs](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-reference.html#useref).

```
import React, { useRef } from "react";

const NavBar = () => {

  const nav = useRef(null);  // initial value of ref null

  return (
    <div className="navbar">
        <nav>
            <ul className="nav-links" ref={nav}>  {/* Put the ref in your JSX */}
                <li>
                    <a href="#">Menu Item</a>
                </li>
            </ul>
        <div
            className="burger"
            onClick={() => {
                nav.current.classList.toggle("nav-active");  // Now you can use the ref here, current is required to get the current value of the ref
            }}
        >
          <div className="line1" />
          <div className="line2" />
          <div className="line3" />
        </div>
       </nav>
    </div>
  );
};

export default NavBar;
```

Comment: Hi is this a more optimal answer compared to the above solution?

Comment: nope, state is the proper thing to do, and unnecessary ref should be avoided. But I wanted to make minimal changes to the code in question. Also state won't be able to handle everything, at some point you will need a ref.